# How do I upload big (video) files in streams to AWS S3 with Laravel 5 and filesystem?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I want to upload a big video file to my AWS S3 bucket. After a good deal of hours, I finally managed to configure my *php.ini* and *nginx.conf* files, so they allowed bigger files.

But then I got a `"Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of XXXXXXXXXX Bytes Exhausted"`. After some time I found out larger files should be uploaded with streams using `fopen()`,`fwrite()`, and `fclose()`.

Since I'm using Laravel 5, the filesystem takes care of much of this. Except that I can't get it to work.

My current `ResourceController@store` looks like this:

```
public function store(ResourceRequest $request)
{
    /* Prepare data */
    $resource = new Resource();
    $key = 'resource-'.$resource->id;
    $bucket = env('AWS_BUCKET');
    $filePath = $request->file('resource')->getRealPath();

    /* Open & write stream */
    $stream = fopen($filePath, 'w');
    Storage::writeStream($key, $stream, ['public']);

    /* Store entry in DB */
    $resource->title = $request->title;
    $resource->save();

    /* Success message */
    session()->flash('message', $request->title . ' uploadet!');
    return redirect()->route('resource-index');
}
```

But now I get this long error:

> CouldNotCreateChecksumException in SignatureV4.php line 148:
>
> A sha256 checksum could not be calculated for the provided upload body, because it was not seekable. To prevent this error you can either 1) include the ContentMD5 or ContentSHA256 parameters with your request, 2) use a seekable stream for the body, or 3) wrap the non-seekable stream in a GuzzleHttp\Stream\CachingStream object. You should be careful though and remember that the CachingStream utilizes PHP temp streams. This means that the stream will be temporarily stored on the local disk.

So I am currently completely lost. I can't figure out if I'm even on the right track. Here are the resource I try to make sense of:

- [AWS SDK guide for PHP: Stream Wrappers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html)
- [AWS SDK introduction on stream wrappers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#uploading-from-a-stream)
- [Flysystem original API on stream wrappers](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/api/#using-streams-for-reads-and-writes)

And just to confuse me even more, there seems to be another way to upload large files other than streams: The so called ["multipart" upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#uploading-large-files-using-multipart-uploads). I actually thought that was what the streams where all about...

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the streaming part applies to downloads.

for uploads you need to know the content size. for large files multipart uploads are the way to go.

Comment: You get an upvote so far for clarifying what I should be focusing on. If you can provide a working code sample, I'll also give you the checkmark. If no better answer has been given before I figure things out myself, you'll get the checkmark regardless. Thanks for your time!

Comment: AWS Multipart-upload worked perfectly! But the upload blocked the page for ages, so I guess I'm off to learn ajax now...

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and came up with this solution.
Instead of using

```
Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);
```

Which of course ran into an "out of memory error" I used this method:

```
use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;
use Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException;

// ...

public function uploadToS3($fromPath, $toPath)
{
    $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
    $uploader = new MultipartUploader($disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient(), $fromPath, [
        'bucket' => Config::get('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
        'key'    => $toPath,
    ]);

    try {
        $result = $uploader->upload();
        echo "Upload complete";
    } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Tested with Laravel 5.1

Here are the official AWS PHP SDK docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html

Comment: Hi HazA, you can help me?, How you add MultipartUploader Class for use on Contoller like UploadController?, thanks!