# Unzip a file in S3 using a stream

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, stream, unzip

We have a zip file containing a large JSON file in it that we need to unzip. We currently fetch the file in a lambda using Laravel, copy and unzip it locally (in the lambda), and then upload the JSON file back to S3 for processing.

It however seems that the lambda doesn't process large files (moving it back to s3 after unzipping in the lambda). (180MB). We could continue to up the lambda resources (deployed via Laravel Vapor), however, we're looking for an in-memory option that could perhaps provide a streaming way of unzipping.

Is there such a solution for PHP?

Comment: This seems to have worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989133/how-do-i-upload-big-video-files-in-streams-to-aws-s3-with-laravel-5-and-filesy

Comment: How big is your file? You can set the memory size of your lambda to max (10240) and max time (900 seconds) i think. Do you necessarily have to use PHP? If you are open to using Python, here's a good tutorial? https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9